# Wordpress ACF fields not showing or letting me update them on POST request

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create an application. I created a custom post type and added custom fields using ACF. When I try to post to save the data, it doesn't save it and when I create one inside wordpress and request it using it's ID, it doesn't show the data in the response.
Below is the JSON (I tried with acf, fields and with leaving everything outside of an object), response and URL.

```json
{
    "title": "title 7",
    "acf": {
        "feeling": "ok",
        "feeling_at_the_moment": "relieved",
        "what_have_you_been_doing": "chores",
        "cognitive_distortions": "",
        "challenge": "",
        "interpretation": "",
        "feeling_now": "",
        "email": "gmail.com"
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "id": 4392,
    "date": "2022-12-03T19:49:14",
    "date_gmt": "2022-12-03T19:49:14",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "/?post_type=mood_tracker&p=4392",
        "raw": "/?post_type=mood_tracker&p=4392"
    },
    "modified": "2022-12-03T19:49:14",
    "modified_gmt": "2022-12-03T19:49:14",
    "password": "",
    "slug": "",
    "status": "draft",
    "type": "mood_tracker",
    "link": "/?post_type=mood_tracker&p=4392",
    "title": {
        "raw": "title 7",
        "rendered": "title 7"
    },
    "content": {
        "raw": "",
        "rendered": "",
        "protected": false,
        "block_version": 0
    },
    "featured_media": 0,
    "template": "",
    "meta": {
        "_mi_skip_tracking": false
    },
    "permalink_template": "/mood_tracker/%pagename%/",
    "generated_slug": "title-7",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wp/v2/mood_tracker/4392"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wp/v2/mood_tracker"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wp/v2/types/mood_tracker"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=4392"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-publish": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wp/v2/mood_tracker/4392"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-unfiltered-html": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wp/v2/mood_tracker/4392"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
https://link.com/wp-json/wp/v2/mood_tracker
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the [ACF document](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/). Make sure this is turned on

[image]

Make sure you do the same while you are creating the custom field group in case it overwrites the general settings

[image]

Sometimes I need to republish the already created posts so they get affected

Comment: Hello, that option is not available for me. Can't see it on my settings section of the field group.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your post group here. also, collapse all the fields

Comment: Also how about the ACF general settings?